# generar un datagridview y condicionar las columnas que tendrá con checkbox

Tags: c#

Buenas quiero generar un datagridview pero las columnas que tendrá deberían condicionarse con los chekbox marcados en otro formulario
C# Windows Forms

Comment: Dkey, bienvenid@ a SOes. Porfavor has el [tour]. Antes de que tu pregunta sea cerrada, ten a bien [edit] tu pregunta y agregar un [mcve].

Comment: 4 cosas: 1. Bienvenido a SOes 2. Revisa https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso obtengas tu primera medalla. Revisa también https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 3. Si dejas la pregunta como está, que no te sorprenda que la cierren. 4. Edita la pregunta contanto qué has hecho, código que intentaste, problema en sí, línea de error y describe el escenario que tienes. Saludos :D

Comment: No evaluaste definir las columnas usando codigo, siempre se puede usar `DataGridView1.Columns.Add()`, pero como comunicas los formularios?